# NullpointException at getActivity() after fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm fighting with this for a week, without luck.

From the begining:

There is an Activity with Navigation Drawer included. This activity has it's own fragments. Fragments have logic to send requests to a weather api and logic to update themselves with given data. At the first run everything seems to work fine! I'm able to send request and fill views with given data (using okHttp).

Everything is starting to collapse after fragments recreations, I'm getting constantly getActivity() to be null ;(

Code Sample below:

Fragments first initialisation:

```
public abstract class DoubleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected static final String TOP_FRAGMENT = "TOP_FRAGMENT";
    protected static final String BOTTOM_FRAGMENT = "BOTTOM_FRAGMENT";
    protected abstract Fragment topFragment();
    protected abstract Fragment bottomFragment();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.topFragmentContainer, topFragment(), TOP_FRAGMENT)
                    .add(R.id.bottomFragmentContainer, bottomFragment(), BOTTOM_FRAGMENT)
                    .commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }
}
```

Navigation Drawer:

```
 private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment f;
        Fragment f2;

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.forecastFragment:
                f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TOP_FRAGMENT");
                f2 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("BOTTOM_FRAGMENT");
                if (f != mCurrentForecastFragment || f2 != mDailyForecastFragment) {
                    ft.replace(R.id.topFragmentContainer, new CurrentForecastFragment(), "TOP_FRAGMENT");
                    ft.replace(R.id.bottomFragmentContainer, new DailyForecastFragment(), "BOTTOM_FRAGMENT");
                } else {

                }
               break;
            case R.id.settingsFragment:
                mToolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                f = new SettingsFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.topFragmentContainer, f);
                break;
            case R.id.paymentsFragment:
                f = new PaymentsFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.topFragmentContainer, f);
                break;
            case R.id.aboutFragment:
                break;
            default:
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        ft.commit();

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
        }
```

Fragment`s logic for connecting and fullfilling data:

```
public void makeConnectionToApi(String lat, String lon) {
       mWeatherParams.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        Activity a = getActivity();

        Uri.Builder currentBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
        currentBuilder.scheme("http")
                .authority("api.openweathermap.org")
                .appendPath("data")
                .appendPath("2.5")
                .appendPath("weather")
                .appendQueryParameter(WeatherConstants.KEY_LATITUDE, lat)
                .appendQueryParameter(WeatherConstants.KEY_LONGITUDE, lon)
                .appendQueryParameter(WeatherConstants.KEY_UNITS, mUnit)
                .appendQueryParameter(WeatherConstants.KEY_LANGUAGE, mWeatherParams.getLanguage())
                .appendQueryParameter("APPID", "###");

        String currentUrl = currentBuilder.build().toString();
        if (mUtility.isNetworkAvalaible()) {
            Request requestCurrent = new Request.Builder().url(currentUrl).build();


            //FIRST CALL
            mCall = client.newCall(requestCurrent);
            mCall.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(TAG, e.toString());
                    Utility.invokeDialog(TAG, e.toString(), getFragmentManager());
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    String responseBody = String.valueOf(response.body().string());
                    try {
                        mForecast.setCurrent(fetchCurrent(responseBody));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            fillViewWithValues();

                        }
                    });
                }
            });


        } else {
            Utility.invokeDialog(TAG, "Check your internet connection!", getFragmentManager());
        }
    }


    private Current fetchCurrent(String responseBody) throws JSONException {
        Current current = new Current();

        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(responseBody);

        //FETCH WEATHER ARRAY
        JSONArray weather = jo.getJSONArray(WeatherConstants.KEY_CURRENT_CONDITIONS_ARRAY);
        for (int j = 0; j < weather.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject weatherParser = weather.getJSONObject(j);
            current.setIcon(weatherParser.getString(WeatherConstants.KEY_ICON_ID));
            Log.i(TAG, "Icons ID: " + weatherParser.getString(WeatherConstants.KEY_ICON_ID));
            current.setConditions(weatherParser.getString(WeatherConstants.KEY_DESCRIPTION));
        }

        //FETCH TEMP
        JSONObject temp = jo.getJSONObject(WeatherConstants.KEY_MAIN_OBJECT);
        current.setDay(temp.getDouble(WeatherConstants.KEY_TEMP));
        current.setPressure(temp.getDouble(WeatherConstants.KEY_PRESSURE));
        current.setHumidity(temp.getDouble(WeatherConstants.KEY_HUMIDITY));
        current.setDayMax(temp.getDouble(WeatherConstants.KEY_TEMP_DAY_MAX));

//        FETCH VISIBILITY
        if (jo.has(WeatherConstants.KEY_VISIBILITY)) {
            current.setVisibility(jo.getInt(WeatherConstants.KEY_VISIBILITY));
        }

        //FETCH WIND

        JSONObject wind = jo.getJSONObject(WeatherConstants.KEY_WIND_OBJECT);
        current.setWindSpeed(wind.getDouble(WeatherConstants.KEY_WIND_SPEED));
        if (wind.has(WeatherConstants.KEY_WIND_DEGREES)) {
            current.setWindDegrees(wind.getInt(WeatherConstants.KEY_WIND_DEGREES));
        }


        JSONObject clouds = jo.getJSONObject(WeatherConstants.KEY_CLOUDS);
        current.setClouds(clouds.getInt("all"));
        current.setTimeStamp(jo.getInt(WeatherConstants.KEY_TIMESTAMP));
        current.setCurrentLocation(jo.getString(WeatherConstants.KEY_CITY_NAME));

        return current;
    }

    private void fillViewWithValues() {
        Current current = mForecast.getCurrent();
        if (mDeegreSwitch == 0) {
            mCurrentTemperature.setText(current.getDay() + "\u00B0");
//            setBackgroundColor(current.getDay());
        } else {
            int c = current.getDay();
            double f = (9.0 / 5.0) * c + 32;
            int e = (int) Math.round(f);

            mCurrentTemperature.setText(String.valueOf((int) Math.round(f)) + "\u00B0");
//            setBackgroundColor(e);
        }

        mCurrentCondition.setText(current.getConditions());
        mPressure.setText(String.valueOf(current.getPressure()) + "hPa");
        mClouds.setText(String.valueOf(current.getClouds()) + "%");
        mHumidity.setText(String.valueOf(current.getHumidity()) + "%");

        mCurrentIcon.setImageResource(current.getIcon());

    }
```

Problems occurs here: getActivity().runOnUiThread inside makeConnectionToApi method. I've tried to fetch an activity from onAttach method and pass it makeConnectionToApi as parameter, it worked...but partially. App didn't crash but fragment`s view was not updated, like there was a second fragment underneath or something.

I have filling it might be something with threads or I'm doing sth wrong with fragments transaction...

Comment: Ok, I will answer to myself: I'm keep getting those NullPointerException errors because I want to fill views in onAttach() method which is invoked a far far before onCreateView() is! I have to wait for onCreateView() to perform those actions! Problem solved!  It was so easy!